# Finding max value of multiple columns in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

How can I find maximum value on multiple columns.
This is what I have so far.

```
With Temp AS (
    SELECT P.ID AS 'Product_ID',
           P.ProductCode AS 'Product_Code',
           P.Name AS 'Product_Name',
           P.SellPrice AS 'SellPrice',
           P.SellPrice+(P.SellPrice*TVA/100) AS 'PricePerUnit',
           P.TVA AS 'TVA',
           P.Discount AS 'Discount_Product',
           0 AS 'Discount_Code',
           0 AS 'Discount_Newsletter',
           V.ID AS 'Variant_ID',
           V.Nume AS 'Variant_Name',
           V.Stock-V.Reserved AS 'Quantity_MAX',
           T.Quantity AS 'Quantity',
           I.ImageName AS 'Image',
           0 AS 'Is_Kit'
    FROM TemporaryShoppingCart T
    INNER JOIN ProductVariant V ON V.ID=T.Variant_ID
    INNER JOIN Product P ON P.ID=V.ProductID
    LEFT JOIN ProductImage I  ON I.ProductID=P.ID AND DefaultImage=1
    WHERE T.ID=@ID AND T.Variant_ID!=0

 ) SELECT t.* ,MAX(MAXValue) FROM (SELECT (T.Discount_Product) AS 'MAXValue' 
                               UNION ALL 
                               SELECT (T.Discount_Code) 
                               UNION ALL 
                               SELECT (T.Discount_Newsletter)) as 'maxval' //error 
   FROM Temp T
```

This code is giving me the error: *Incorrect syntax near 'maxval'.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you simply looking for GREATEST?

```
SELECT
  t.*, 
  GREATEST(T.Discount_Product, T.Discount_Code, T.Discount_Newsletter) as 'maxval' 
FROM Temp T;
```

However GREATEST Returns NULL when a value is NULL, so you might want to care about this, too. For instance:

```
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  GREATEST
  (
    coalesce(T.Discount_Product,0), 
    coalesce(T.Discount_Code, 0), 
    coalesce(T.Discount_Newsletter, 0)
  ) as 'maxval' 
FROM Temp T;
```

EDIT: In case GREATEST is not available in your dbms you can use a case expression.

```
SELECT 
  t.*, 
  CASE 
    WHEN coalesce(T.Discount_Product, 0) > coalesce(T.Discount_Code, 0)
     AND coalesce(T.Discount_Product, 0) > coalesce(T.Discount_Newsletter, 0)
     THEN coalesce(T.Discount_Product, 0)
    WHEN coalesce(T.Discount_Code, 0) > coalesce(T.Discount_Product, 0)
     AND coalesce(T.Discount_Code, 0) > coalesce(T.Discount_Newsletter, 0)
     THEN coalesce(T.Discount_Code, 0)
    ELSE coalesce(T.Discount_Newsletter, 0)
  END
FROM Temp T;
```

EDIT: To get your own statement syntactically correct, do:

```
SELECT 
  t.*,
  (
    select MAX(Value) 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT T.Discount_Product AS Value 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT T.Discount_Code
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT T.Discount_Newsletter
    ) dummy -- T-SQL requires a name for such sub-queries
  ) as maxval
FROM Temp T;
```

Comment: It didn't work. I get the error: 'GREATEST' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Otix: Too bad. Most dbms support GREATEST. What dbms are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: True, SQL Server doesn't support it. I've edited my answer to show how to solve it in standard SQL with CASE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. But I'm still waiting for the answer why at my approach I get error.

Comment: That's a syntax error. You cannot simply put your code with a from clause in that statement. To you it Looks obvious what you are doing, because of indention. The dbms doesn't. It sees two from clauses. Make MAX(MAXValue) FROM ... a sub-select. well, I'll show you above...

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to have each `Select` statement to have a From clause.

Comment: He means when you do select, you need a from. Hence your syntax errors in the question above

Answer (score 0):

SELECT max( GREATEST(`col1`,`col2`, `col3`,`col4`, `col5`, `col6`, `col7`, `col8`, `col9`,`col10`, `col11`, `col12`)) AS 'MAXDATE' FROM table_name

Answer (score 0):

Consider we have three tables C1,C2 and C3.

The table data are as follow :-

[image]

To find the 1st max value we use the following sql query:

**Query:**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT (T.Marks) AS Highest, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  MAX(T.MARKS) DESC) AS R FROM
(
SELECT (c1.Marks) AS Marks FROM c1 
UNION
SELECT (c2.Marks) AS Marks FROM c2 
UNION 
SELECT (c3.Marks) AS Marks FROM c3 
) AS T   GROUP BY (T.Marks) )
SELECT Highest FROM CTE WHERE R = 1
```

[image]

To find the next max values change the value of R in last line of query.